# Unable to deploy express js project into vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, vercel

I worked on expressjs project, Project working fine in localhost,Now i am trying to upload using vercel, i am not getting any error but i am getting following message
404: NOT_FOUND
How can i fix this ? Can we upload express js project ? and how to integrate database ? Thank you in advance.